# search worksheet for a a variable and populate listbox

Tags: excel, vba

after selecting a combobox I then need to search/find in a specific worksheet for a match, then return all matching rows of a column and populate a 2nd combobox.

This is called from a userform in VB Modal

```
   Public Function GetArtistRange() As Range
    
     ' Get the data range from the Artists worksheet
    Set GetArtistRange = shArtists.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    ' remove the header from the range by moving the range down one row and then removing the last row.
    Set GetArtistRange = GetArtistRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetArtistRange.Rows.Count - 1)

End Function 
    Private Sub loadListboxes()
   'gets data from Module above
    ddlArtist.List = ModuleRange.GetArtists()
    ddlArtist.ListIndex = -1
       
End Sub
Private Sub ddlArtist_Click()
'Need help searching shInventory worksheet for all rows that match the value of ddlArtists.value in shInventory Column B (artists name) and Column G (status) = "A". 
'And return all the artworks in Column C (artworks) and bind to combobox 2
End Sub
enter code he
```

Hope this helps?

Ok I have managed to get something working, this code does find and returns matching inventory items, and adds to 2nd list box.

```
ddlArtwork.Clear
        Dim finalrow As Range
    Set finalrow = shInventory.ListObjects("tblInventory").Range.Rows   'Sets finalrow = to entire data table range
    
    'The range below as the index of your for loop
    Dim aRow As Range
    For Each aRow In finalrow
        If aRow.Value2(1, 2) = ddlArtist.Value Then
        
            ddlArtwork.AddItem (aRow.Value2(1, 3))
            
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Comment: H. I  have created some userform front ends to manage a small sales and inventory application for a group of artists.
When a user is adding new sale, he selects the artist from a combo box, this is already working using a public function - Set GetArtistRange = shArtists.Range("A2").CurrentRegion
    ' remove the header from the range by moving the range down one row and
    ' then removing the last row.
    Set GetArtistRange = GetArtistRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetArtistRange.Rows.Count - 1)

Comment: in click event I need to find and add items in Inventory worksheet that match artists name to 2nd Combo box.. Not sure how to format my code for this?

Comment: The `Edit` button is just below the tags on your original question.  Can you edit your question with the code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ddlArtwork.Clear
    Dim finalrow As Range
Set finalrow = shInventory.ListObjects("tblInventory").Range.Rows   'Sets finalrow = to entire data table range

'The range below as the index of your for loop
Dim aRow As Range
For Each aRow In finalrow
    If aRow.Value2(1, 2) = ddlArtist.Value Then
    
        ddlArtwork.AddItem (aRow.Value2(1, 3))
        
    End If
Next
```